# how to change pipe size in c (or let parent get child's value without using pipe)

Tags: c, arrays, process, pipe, fork

in my multi-process program, child processes change the array's context concurrently and parent reads. for the parent to read the array updated by the child processes, i am told to use `pipe` and it worked! the problem is i cannot use `ARRAY_SIZE` more than 65600ish, i need it to be 5000000.

so apparently, with `fcntl` it can be changed.
in `main`, i did this:

```
if(pipe(fd) == -1)
    perror("pipe");
fcntl(fd[1],F_SETPIPE_SZ,5000000);
```

it says `F_SETPIPE_SZ` is undeclared.

if i move it outside the `main`, it says:

```
error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before numeric constant
```

instead of dealing with these, is there any other way to make the parent read the updated array? (this is an assignment so i don't think they'd push too hard to be honest, so i believe there must be an easier way)

**edit:** i wonder how to achieve this by not changing the pipe size. here is my code. this code does print what i want but it takes `Total time = 1459086139.792471 seconds.` in this assignment the main idea is to see the difference between execution times of a single process program and a multi-process program. single process program takes 37 seconds. so, this result cannot be right, right? i tried to move the part after `//another attempt` to the outside of the loop, it does not work, it does not give any errors too, does nothing.

```
        for(j = 0; j<NUM_OF_SUBARRAYS; j++)
    {
    start = (SUBARRAY_SIZE*j);
    child_pid = fork(); 

    switch (child_pid)
        {
    case -1:        
        perror("fork"); 
        exit(1);
    case 0:     
        child_process_routine(start);
        exit(0);
    default:
        waitpid(-1, NULL, 0);
        //another attempt
        close(fd[1]);
        for (i = 0; i<ARRAY_SIZE; i++)
        {
        read(fd[0], &temp, sizeof(temp));
        printf("%c ",temp);
        }
        close(fd[0]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: The upper bound is likely to be 65535 (2^16 - 1).  You can find [`F_SETPIPE_SZ`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fcntl.2.html) in `<fcntl.h>` if you have a sufficiently recent version of Linux.  Why do you need the limit to be bigger?  If you design the data on the wire properly and have a single reader thread/process, then you can write and read the data unambiguously.

Comment: i do have a single reader process which is the parent. there is a `for` loop which creates child processes, in its `default` case (in parent code) it waits for the child processes. after for loop, parent's code can continue, right? i put the `read` code there. it didn't work. (no error, just nothing happened) i put the `read` code in `default` case after wait. it prints the elements, but never stops

Comment: i added more information, please check

Comment: The printed 'total time' value is the current UNIX time stamp, not the time your program was running.  The duplicate question deals with why you get the `F_SETPIPE_SZ` undefined error.  You can't afford to ignore the return value from `read()`.  You should be reading more than one byte at a time.  There is nowhere near enough code for this to be an MCVE ([MCVE]), and without an MCVE, it will be hard to help you.  Pay attention to the duplicate.  Ask a new question with an MCVE.